# Min and max date of blocks of subsequent days

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, partitioning

I have a table where i need to find minimum date and maximum date from blocks of subsequent days. My Sample table is as below :

| Id | Startdate | Enddate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 2017-06-01 | 2017-06-01 |
| 1001 | 2017-06-01 | 2017-06-10 |
| 1001 | 2017-06-02 | 2017-06-03 |
| 1001 | 2017-06-02 | 2017-06-02 |
| 1001 | 2017-06-04 | 2017-06-10 |
| 1001 | 2018-06-08 | 2018-06-08 |
| 1001 | 2018-06-09 | 2018-06-09 |
| 1001 | 2018-06-10 | 2018-06-10 |
| 1001 | 2018-06-11 | 2018-06-11 |
| 1001 | 2018-06-12 | 2018-06-12 |
| 1001 | 2018-06-13 | 2018-06-13 |
| 1001 | 2018-06-14 | 2018-06-14 |
| 1001 | 2018-06-15 | 2018-06-15 |
| 1001 | 2019-02-01 | 2019-02-03 |
| 1001 | 2019-02-01 | 2019-02-06 |
| 1001 | 2019-02-01 | 2019-02-01 |
| 1001 | 2019-02-02 | 2019-02-02 |
| 1001 | 2019-02-03 | 2019-02-03 |
| 1001 | 2019-02-04 | 2019-02-06 |
| 1001 | 2019-02-04 | 2019-02-04 |
| 1001 | 2019-02-05 | 2019-02-05 |
| 1001 | 2019-02-06 | 2019-02-06 |
| 1001 | 2019-05-23 | 2019-05-23 |
| 1001 | 2019-05-24 | 2019-05-24 |

Expected Output :

| Id | Startdate | Enddate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 2017-06-01 | 2017-06-10 |
| 1001 | 2018-06-08 | 2018-06-15 |
| 1001 | 2019-02-01 | 2019-02-06 |
| 1001 | 2019-05-23 | 2019-05-24 |

I understand this can be achieved only by PARTITION BY . I tried with below but it doesnt seem to be working. Please advise.

```
SELECT ID,
MIN(STARTDATE)  AS STARTDATE ,MAX(ENDDATE) AS ENDDATE
  FROM (SELECT MEMBER_ID,STARTDATE,ENDDATE ,COUNT (IS_GAP) OVER (ORDER BY MEMBER_ID,STARTDATE) AS RANGE_ID
  FROM (SELECT  MEMBER_ID,STARTDATE,ENDDATE , CASE WHEN MAX (ENDDATE) OVER 
  (PARTITION BY MEMBER_ID ORDER BY MEMBER_ID, STARTDATE ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING ) < STARTDATE THEN  TRUE END AS IS_GAP
FROM  TABLE T ) T) T
GROUP BY    RANGE_ID, MEMBER_ID
ORDER BY MEMBER_ID,STARTDATE;
```

Thanking you in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the classic time gap problem.

- First, I need to build some time set that I will be based on, in my case it's the  **_days** subquery.
- Then I need to compute the instance groups, I use the DENSE_RANK and DATEDIFF functions to investigate the difference, this creates groups.
- Then just aggregation within these groups and we have the result.

Sample data:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE T1 (
    Id INT,
    Startdate DATE,
    Enddate DATE
);

INSERT INTO T1(Id, Startdate, Enddate)
SELECT *
FROM VALUES 
(1001, '2017-06-01', '2017-06-01'),
(1001, '2017-06-01', '2017-06-10'),
(1001, '2017-06-02', '2017-06-03'),
(1001, '2017-06-02', '2017-06-02'),
(1001, '2017-06-04', '2017-06-10'),
(1001, '2018-06-08', '2018-06-08'),
(1001, '2018-06-09', '2018-06-09'),
(1001, '2018-06-10', '2018-06-10'),
(1001, '2018-06-11', '2018-06-11'),
(1001, '2018-06-12', '2018-06-12'),
(1001, '2018-06-13', '2018-06-13'),
(1001, '2018-06-14', '2018-06-14'),
(1001, '2018-06-15', '2018-06-15'),
(1001, '2019-02-01', '2019-02-03'),
(1001, '2019-02-01', '2019-02-06'),
(1001, '2019-02-01', '2019-02-01'),
(1001, '2019-02-02', '2019-02-02'),
(1001, '2019-02-03', '2019-02-03'),
(1001, '2019-02-04', '2019-02-06'),
(1001, '2019-02-04', '2019-02-04'),
(1001, '2019-02-05', '2019-02-05'),
(1001, '2019-02-06', '2019-02-06'),
(1001, '2019-05-23', '2019-05-23'),
(1001, '2019-05-24', '2019-05-24') t(Id, Startdate, Enddate);
```

Solution:

```
SET MINDATE = (SELECT MIN(Startdate) FROM T1);
SET MAXDATE = (SELECT MAX(Enddate) FROM T1);
SET DIFFDAYS = (SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, $MINDATE, $MAXDATE)+1);

WITH _days AS (
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, SEQ4(), $MINDATE) AS Day
      FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT => $DIFFDAYS))
), _grps AS (
  SELECT *
       , DATEDIFF(DAY, $MINDATE, D.Day) - DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY T1.Id ORDER BY D.Day) AS grp
    FROM _days AS D
    JOIN T1 ON D.Day BETWEEN T1.Startdate AND T1.Enddate
)
SELECT ID
     , MIN(Day) AS Startdate
     , MAX(Day) AS Enddate    
  FROM _grps
 GROUP BY Id, grp;
```

Comment: Working Perfect !!! Thanks @Michael Golos